# How to change jquery datepicker style dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm struggling with a jquery datepicker which changes style dynamically. What I want to do is, if checkbox is clicked then datepicker shows only year and month, if not, datepicker works as normal with year, month and date.

I wrote below script. I could see below script was triggered and didn't show any problem, but it didn't work.

If anyone knows what the problem is, please help me. That would be great, thank you.

===== edit =====

With Barmar's advice, I could make this working to change dateFormat dynamically. But I still can't toggle displaying calendar part of datepicker which I'm trying with `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar").css({ "display": "none" });` and `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar").css({ "display": "inline-block" });`

Does anybody know the solution for this?

```
function addEventCheckBox() {
    $("#checkBoxForFlag").live("click", function(e) {
        changeDatePicker();
    });
}

function changeDatePicker() {
    var flag = $("#checkBoxForFlag").is(":checked");

    if (flag) {
        $("#testDate").datepicker("option", {
            dateFormat: "yy/mm"
        });

        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").css({ "display": "none" });
    } else {
        $("#testDate").datepicker("option", {
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        });

        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").css({ "display": "inline-block" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML or a JSFiddle?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I didn't actually see your comment before I submitted my answer - wasn't trying to poach, we just came to the same conclusion at the same time -

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.8. And I confirmed `.live()` works well. Anyway thank guys for your adivces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.datepicker(<options>)` function can only be used to initialize a new datepicker. To change an existing datepicker, use the [`option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) method. You can give either an object containing the options you're changing, or just one option as a single argument.

```
function changeDatePicker() {
    var flag = $("#checkBoxForFlag").is(":checked");

    if (flag) {
        $("#testDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm");
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    } else {
        $("#testDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm/dd");
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer; upvoting this one and deleting my answer -

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. It works!!! However, `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();` doesn't work, do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Did it work when you used `.css()` as in your question? `.hide()` should be the same as `.css("display", "none")`

Comment: No, it didn't work, only when I wrote it in `<style/>` of html, it worked. But I'm trying to make it work dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimental tries, I solved this issue. So I'm writing the solution here for someone who might have same problem.

```
function changeDatePicker() {
  var flag = $("#checkBoxForFlag").is(":checked");

  if (flag) {
    $("#testDate").datepicker("destroy");
    $("#testDate").datepicker({
      showOn: "both",
      buttonImageOnly: false,
      dateFormat: "yy/mm",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      maxDate: 0,
      buttonText: "",
      onClose: function () {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      }
    });
  $("#testDate").focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
        my: "center top",
        at: "center bottom",
        of: $(this)
    });
  });
  $("#testDate").blur(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
  });
  } else {
    $("#testDate").datepicker("destroy");
    $("#testDate").datepicker({
      showOn: "both",
      buttonImageOnly: false,
      dateFormat: userDateFormat_datepicker,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      maxDate: 0,
      buttonText: ""
    });
    $("#testDate").focus(function () {
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").show();
    });
    $("#testDate").blur(function () {
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").show();
    });
  }
}
```